# Applying MSP to MSI without installing MSI

Tags: windows-installer

I am generating a repository of dependencies and their respective versions. I am able to extract the MSI using

msiexec /a "c:\temp\2\MyMSI.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="c:\extracted" REINSTALLMODE="amus" REINSTALL="ALL"

This part is working fine, but when I go to apply the MSP I can not get it to work.

I have tried

- msiexec /a "c:\temp\MyMSI.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="C:\extracted" REINSTALLMODE="amus" PATCH="c:\temp\MyPatch.msp"
- msiexec /a "C:\extracted\MyMSI.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="C:\extracted" REINSTALLMODE="amus" PATCH="c:\temp\MyPatch.msp"
- msiexec /a "C:\extracted\MyMSI.msi" /p "c:\temp\MyPatch.msp"
- msiexec /a "C:\temp\MyMSI.msi" /p "c:\temp\MyPatch.msp"
- several others with success

I keep getting the message

[image: Error Message]

The message makes sense because I have not ACTUALLY installed the MSI but I need to get the updated files from the patch.

I should note that this is being run in a loop over approx. 60 msi so I would prefer minimal manual steps.

UPDATE: Below are the entries from the log

```
MSI (c) (60:68) [16:19:02:645]: SequencePatches starts. Product code: {1B7D2B53-5A7D-4227-9441-BDB9F1047672}, Product version: 15.1.15.28, Upgrade code: {2DB5D3D4-42AF-49D4-B6B5-B4F9540DA781}, Product language 1033
MSI (c) (60:68) [16:19:02:645]: PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of minor upgrade patch c:\ININ\IceLibSDK_32bit_2015_R1_Patch6.msp against product code: {1B7D2B53-5A7D-4227-9441-BDB9F1047672}, product version: 15.1.15.28, product language 1033 and upgrade code: {2DB5D3D4-42AF-49D4-B6B5-B4F9540DA781}
MSI (c) (60:68) [16:19:02:646]: PATCH SEQUENCER: minor upgrade patch c:\ININ\IceLibSDK_32bit_2015_R1_Patch6.msp is not applicable.
MSI (c) (60:68) [16:19:02:646]: SequencePatches returns success.
MSI (c) (60:68) [16:19:02:646]: Final Patch Application Order:
MSI (c) (60:68) [16:19:02:646]: Other Patches:
MSI (c) (60:68) [16:19:02:646]: Unknown\Absent: {71E3B59E-4380-4145-B1A5-20ECDC68FEF7} - c:\ININ\IceLibSDK_32bit_2015_R1_Patch6.msp
The upgrade cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade.
```

Comment: MPSs are intended to be applied to installed programs, that's what they're for. So what is your goal here? To extract the files from the patch file?

Comment: Yes, to apply the updates from the patch to the administrative install location so I can ultimately repackage the files. The point of an MSI is to install the programs, but you are able to do an administrative install to extract them. I want to do the same with the MSP file to "Patch" the extracted files from the MSI.

Comment: If you haven't already, try this format: `msiexec.exe /a "[path to .msi file]" /p "[path to .msp file]"`

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Just tried with same error, updating question with this attempt. - I am beginning to wonder if the error is actually from MSIEXEC or is the patch might have a customaction defined doing some sort of not standard check.

Comment: If you actually DO install that MSI, does applying that patch work?

Comment: Yes so I know the patch is good but since there are so many different versions I am not wanting to have to install, patch, extract uninstall patch install next patch and so on for each version. If I have to then I will spin up a VM and use snapshots to do this rather than on my physical build server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK for anyone else that runs into this requirement, I had to do this in 2 stages

1. msiexec /a "c:\temp\mymsi.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="c:\temp2" REINSTALLMODE="amus"
2. msiexec /a "**c:\temp2\mymsi.msi**" /qb TARGETDIR="c:\temp2" REINSTALLMODE="amus" PATCH="c:\temp\mypatch.msp"

NOTE the 2nd step is using the NEW msi from step1. I could not get it to work in a single step.